# ROC Curve Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I've already seen other questions that address the issue that python scikit-learn's roc_curve function might return numbers of values a lot less than the number of data points and I know that this happens when there are a small number of unique values in the probability values.

The following is the output of the first iteration of the for loop shown below:

`y_test:  [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.
 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
probas:  [0.97980869 0.61031697 0.9463976  0.07607395 0.93956894 0.06914656
 0.64741115 0.07618758 0.95895803 0.83249766 0.13942336 0.7326476
 0.93728438 0.07894027 0.97504296 0.92879864 0.93744224 0.21646299
 0.95141726 0.92728865 0.97493415 0.07854641 0.95159664 0.36212405
 0.21415855 0.10376292 0.95303641 0.11629533 0.93807975 0.7540189
 0.93019584 0.94054764 0.93755026 0.93893753 0.95637685 0.10910955
 0.96091857 0.95273078 0.61031697 0.9745807  0.11621697 0.97879922
 0.96512002 0.09424992]`

Code:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    print("y_test: ", y_test[:, 1])
    print("probas: ", probas_[:, i])
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, 1], probas_[:, i], pos_label=1)
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

print("fpr", fpr)
print("tpr", tpr)
print("roc", roc_auc)
```

Result:

```
fpr {0: array([0., 0., 0., 1.]), 1: array([0.        , 0.03571429, 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ]), 'micro': array([0.        , 0.02272727, 0.95454545, 0.95454545, 1.        ,
           1.        ])}

tpr {0: array([0.0625, 0.875 , 1.    , 1.    ]), 1: array([0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.125, 1.   ]), 'micro': array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.04545455, 0.04545455,
           1.        ])}

roc {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 'micro': 0.002066115702479337}
```

There are FOUR points for both FPR and TPR!!! Why is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: it depends on the input arrays (on sorted probabilities whether actual labels change), for a different array of same size, you will get different length

Comment: What do you mean a different array? Y_true and the probabilities are of the same length.

Comment: use this array for probabilities - [0.97980869 ,0.61031697 ,0.9463976  ,0.07607395 ,0.93956894 ,0.06914656
 ,0.64741115 ,0.07618758 ,0.95895803 ,0.83249766 ,0.13942336 ,0.7326476
 ,0.93728438 ,0.07894027 ,0.97504296 ,0.92879864 ,0.93744224 ,0.21646299
 ,0.95141726 ,0.0001 ,0.97493415 ,0.00002 ,0.00003 ,0.36212405
 ,0.21415855 ,0.10376292 ,0.95303641 ,0.11629533 ,0.93807975 ,0.7540189
 ,0.93019584 ,0.94054764 ,0.93755026 ,0.93893753 ,0.95637685 ,0.10910955
 ,0.96091857 ,0.95273078 ,0.61031697 ,0.9745807  ,0.11621697 ,0.97879922
 ,0.96512002 ,0.09424992], you will get length 7

Comment: like use len(arr)? What do you mean by length?

Comment: I mean to say that the length of the output array is determined by the actual input (not just the length of input), for more details, see line 356 in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py#L453

Comment: And that has to do with whether the values in the input are unique right? "y_score typically has many tied values. Here we extract the indices associated with the distinct values. We also concatenate a value for the end of the curve". My question is, why do I get so little values when all my values for the probabilities are unique? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html), you need to provide `roc_curve` with the probability of the positive class. I don't think you are doing this. What is the shape of `y_test` and `probas`?

Comment: Oh the shapes are (44,2) for both and with the for loop I iterate with the positive class and the negative class. I calculate the ROC for the first class and the ROC for the second class.. This was taken from example here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py

Comment: @Chan Woo. That is for multiclass, you have binary (1 or 0), so it is more simple. I'm confused why y_test has shape (44,2), what is in the second column? Anyway, I think your problem is very simple: your data is perfectly classified (using `probas[:,1]`, the prob for the positive class) using a threshold of 0.63, which is why your ROC curve looks like it does. There is a third output from `roc_curve` that you are not looking at: threshold.

Comment: I made it a one hot encoding thing where it's either [1,0] or [0,1] to follow the example in the multi class example - i guess that was unnecessary. So if I feed just probability for the positive class and 0 or 1 for true values it would work? Also I get that 0.63 thing but there should be more nuance to that with values lower than 0.63 and have a tpr and fpr values for lower thresholds right?

Comment: @Chan Woo, something like `fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probas[:,1])`. No, not in your case. If you start with a threshold of 0 and increase it, recording the TPR and FPR each time, you will only really have 3 values because everything is correctly classified at 0.63. e.g. Threshold =[0,0.63,1], TPR=[0,1,1] and FPR=[0,0,1]. If you want to see a “more normal” roc curve, then do `fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probas[:,1][::-1])`, which reverses your probabilities. It’s nonsense, of course, but just so you can see the `roc_curve` is working 

Comment: You are not using a parameter `drop_intermediate` which defaults to True and drops 'suboptimal thresholds which would not appear on a plotted ROC curve' . If you set this to False, you will get the same length as your input